# Help with waiting while a process is running

Tags: bash, script

I'm looking for a bash script that checks if the Installer process is running and waits/pause if it then proceeds once the process is no longer running.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 PROCESS="Installer";
 PID=$(ps -A |grep -m1 "$PROCESS" | awk '{print $1}');
 while s=`ps -p $PID -o s=` && [[ "$s" && "$s" !='Z'  ]]; do
     echo "$PROCESS is Running, waiting for it to close"
     sleep 1
 done
 echo "$PROCESS is not Running";
 SCRIPT HERE
```

Comment: We are not a script-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks. Where does it not work as expected?

Comment: Similar to your other question, you need to be sure you are searching for the correct string. Here you are searching for "Installer", which means any process that includes that string will match (e.g. "Installer Progress". I'd adjust this to "Installer.app"

Comment: And to avoid relying on the process showing up before the `grep` I would use `pgrep` instead (which even returns the PID directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your script and changed

- Changed the PID assignment to `pgrep`
- Changed `-o s=` to `-o stat=` for `ps`
- Removed the unnecessary `;` at the end of some lines

It's a bit hard to test, but something like

```
#!/bin/bash
PROCESS="Installer"
PID=$(pgrep "$PROCESS")
while s=`ps -p $PID -o stat=` && [[ "$s" && "$s" != 'Z' ]]; do
    echo "$PROCESS is running, waiting for it to terminate"
    sleep 1
done
echo "$PROCESS is not running anymore"
SCRIPT HERE
```

should work.

If you are not worried about the Installer getting into **Z**ombie state you could rely on the fact that `ps` exits with 1 if no process is found, and significantly simplify the loop condition.